# Custom Component Gets Stuck when switching record types for opportunities

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-apps, path

In our org we have two different paths for two different record types. Record type 1 includes and extra chevron called 'Explore'. When a user is in the 'Explore' chevron and changes the record type to record type 2, the custom component that is just supposed to be available when on the 'Explore' chevron from record type 1 will get stuck and will appear in all chevrons.

Has anything similar happened to anyone here?? New admin in great need of help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am using filters to adjust the visibility for the component. However, they don't seem to be working.